# [docker] ament: command not found

Tags: ros, ros2, docker, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to use the ros2 docker image and could not find the ament executable. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ docker run --rm -it osrf/ros2:ardent-basic bash
# echo $PATH
/opt/ros/ardent/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# which ament
# echo $?
1
# ament build
bash: ament: command not found
# find / -name ament
# echo $0
bash
# source /opt/ros/ardent/setup.bash
# # same results with the commands above. No sense in repeating
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293443/%5Bdocker%5D-ament:-command-not-found/) by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2018-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are doing nothing wrong, the developper tools are not installed in the docker images only the libraries and demo executables (similar to the ROS1 docker images).

If you want to compile code I recommend you to install `ros-ardent-ament*` that will install `ament_tools` (providing the `ament` executable) as well as various ament packages providing utilities for testing.

If you plan on developing ROS2 code, I recommend you to also install all the building dependencies (build-essential, setuptools etc) that are listed in the [Install GCC, G++ CMake, Python 3 EmPy package [...]](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Development-Setup) section of the installation page.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2018-06-19**:
You can also checkout the current ros2 dockerfile that builds ros2 from source and concisely installs core build dependencies:
https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/751b3e37945790b45aa900d2d87eaa4f585fddbc/ros2/source/source/Dockerfile